# DNS server to create hostname with any ip?

Tags: dns

There was some public dns server that creates dns records on the fly, for example 127.0.0.1.something.com that resolves to 127.0.0.1, I searched a lot on Google but I can't find it. Any idea?

Comment: DNS is only for public addresses. You can manually add your hostnames to /etc/resolv.conf or whatever the file in your OS.

Comment: Tasty question.

Comment: Your question will be better suited on [SoftwareRecs.se], as here it should be related to some existing program of yours typically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[xip.io is gone](https://github.com/rancher/quickstart/issues/174) as of June 2021.

http://nip.io is a working alternative.  It works in a similar fashion to xip, so the information below is still valid (changing any references from xip.io to nip.io).

```
$ nslookup  asdf.10.0.0.1.nip.io
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   asdf.10.0.0.1.nip.io
Address: 10.0.0.1
```

Original answer:

You are talking about http://xip.io/

```
What is xip.io?
xip.io is a magic domain name that provides wildcard DNS
for any IP address. Say your LAN IP address is 10.0.0.1.
Using xip.io,

          10.0.0.1.xip.io   resolves to   10.0.0.1
      www.10.0.0.1.xip.io   resolves to   10.0.0.1
   mysite.10.0.0.1.xip.io   resolves to   10.0.0.1
  foo.bar.10.0.0.1.xip.io   resolves to   10.0.0.1

...and so on. You can use these domains to access virtual
hosts on your development web server from devices on your
local network, like iPads, iPhones, and other computers.
No configuration required!
    
How does it work?
xip.io runs a custom DNS server on the public Internet.
When your computer looks up a xip.io domain, the xip.io
DNS server extracts the IP address from the domain and
sends it back in the response.
```

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is loopback address, it is like localhost, always is your pc but that is not in a dns server.

If you want your pc accessible from internet and don't pay for a dns addres use [dyndns](https://dyn.com/dns/) or [no-ip](https://www.noip.com/)

the best part of this sites are that no mind if you have a dynamic ip they always point to your pc

Comment: it was just an example, it could be 123.123.123.123... I'm sure there was that service, it was very useful

Comment: it was a short name, 3 letters I think... someone must know it :))